# How to unbind click event on the active element and bind again when another element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I guess it's easier to explain using an example:

HTML:

```
<div class="boxset">
    <div class="box_header">  
        h1  
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        This is some text for box 1.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="boxset">
    <div class="box_header">  
        h2  
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        This is some text for box 2.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="boxset">
    <div class="box_header">  
        h3  
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        This is some text for box 3.
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.box_header').bind("click", function() {
    $('.box').not($(this).next('.box')).animate({
        'width': 'hide'
    });
    $(this).next().animate({
        'width': 'show'
    });
});
```

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rDHMF/

Here is a simple sideways accordion menu. Now when I click on a header (h1, h2, h3), its corresponding content will show and the previously opened one will close. However, I can click again on that same header I just clicked and it will contract and expand itself.

Is it possible to temporarily unbind the click event on the header I just clicked so that the 'active' header will just stay put when I click on it? Then bind again when I click on another header. If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
$('.box_header').bind("click", function() {
    $('.box').not($(this).next('.box')).animate({
        'width': 'hide'
    });
    $(this).next().animate({
        'width': 'show'
    });
});
```

You don't need to un/rebind the events, just prevent the box from contracting when it's the same

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks. I thought I needed to bind/unbind.

Answer (score 1):

I would do that in a different way. Whenever a user clicks on a header add an `active` class to the header (and remove it from other headers). And do some other thing if this header already has an `active` class (only remove a header from this header and animate). This way also allows us to customize styles on active headers.